# Making a pencil drawing program in java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, drawing, line

I have this code which is a part of the paint program I am making in java. The purpose of this code is to draw anything like a pencil using your mouse. But when you use this code, the squiggles you drew in separate places in the scribble panel unexpectedly join together and I can't figure out why. Please help. Here is the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<this.drawingPoints.size()-1; i++){
            Pair p1=this.drawingPoints.get(i);
            Pair p2=this.drawingPoints.get(i+2);
            g2d.drawLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `get(i+2)` is odd - surely `get(i+1)`? It's also accessing off the end of the array, so I'm surprised you didn't get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Comment: I am sorry but it didnt work